# Is it possible to pause/resume/cancel download from selenium in java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can we control the browser download of pause/resume/cancel downloading from selenium web driver in java. If yes, please provide your suggestions.

Comment: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Let me know the language that you are planning to implement this. So that I can provide your the code snippets.

Comment: In java language